# How to migrate status of a workflow in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, migration

We have a forms library with 6K infopath xml forms. We want the status of a workflow to be migrated to destination site and if possible then to a new custom column in destination. How can we achieve that? In destination site we will have a PowerAutomate flow which will use that new column to update status.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To migrate workflows with status, I suggest you migrate the whole site collection to the destination.